# IdentityServer4 and Security Stamp

Tags: c#, .net-core, identityserver4

I've added an additional claim to the profile scope, **security_stamp**. My intention is to use the security stamp in the call to IsActiveAsync in my custom IProfileService.

I can get all the claims I have requested to show in my MVC client, however, the issue I have is when a call is made to the UserInfoEndPoint it only contains the below 4 claims in the context of a UserInfoRequest. I have no way of knowing what security stamp the client currently holds for this user

[image: claims in UserInfoRequestContext]

How are people handling this in their implementations of Identity Server, am I going about this the wrong way?

I'm not using asp.net identity core. I've used my own user tables

[image]

Comment: Are you able to inspect your access token and see what claims are inside?

Comment: @mackie thanks man, you lead me to the resolution, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @mackie, he lead me to the resolution.

I forgot to mention in my question that I am using hybrid workflow, this means I am requesting an id_token and a code (access code).

my client has the following scopes

```
AllowedScopes =
{
    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId, // Identity resource
    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile, // identity resource
    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email, // identity resource
    "API" // api resource
 },
```

So @mackie's comment made something click, I am requesting an access token that will be used to access my "API" which is defined as an **ApiResource**, so that means the ApiResource needs to know about the **security_stamp** claim.

I updated my ApiResource to the following and it now appears in the UserInfoEndPoint context. Happy days!

```
new ApiResource("API", "API", new [] { "security_stamp" }),
```

A lot of time the frustration comes from not understanding how scopes and claims work together. Its all starting to make a bit more sense now. Every day is a school day!